Jekyll posts render fine in HTML but other collections are simply missing
I am trying to add a changelog to my website. I am using jekyll's collections feature to do so. I have found liquid to be frustratingly opaque and have not yet figured out how to view available properties of any given item, and jekyll's docs are annoyingly silent in regards to collections. Liquid's docs have no mention of them, as they're unique to jekyll. Regardless, trying to render the following liquid (as shown in jekyll documentation) in my site's html simply displays nothing.
{% for item in site.changelog %}
    <p>{{item.content}}</p>
{% endfor %}

I have tried any number of various other configurations to no success. Posts queried from site.posts are perfectly fine though.
Here is my filesystem

This is the relevant section of my _config.yml
collections-dir: Col
collections:
  posts:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:name
  changelog:
    output: false

I'm not sure what I'm missing and I've been banging my head on this for the past 4-5 hours to absolutely no success. Help is greatly appreciated.
